# C# HTTPWebRequest Cannot Be Used to Access a URL Periodically?

Tags: c#, http

I am writing a program to crawl Web pages using C# HTTTWebRequest. Since I need to monitor the updates of a specific URL, I write the code as follows. However, I noticed that I could get responses for two times only. After that, it got no responses. Even though I lengthen the period to one minute, I still got the same problem. I don't understand why. Could you give me a hand? Thanks so much!

GreatFree

```
while (true)
{
    WebRequest http = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.sina.com.cn");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine(response.LastModified);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I got no responses"? Is there an exception, empty response stream, HTTP error?

Comment: The thread gets blocked at the line, HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse(), until a timeout exception.

Answer (score 7):

imaximchuk's answer is correct, but it doesn't explain why.

HTTP connections are pooled - one connection will be reused for a new request if it's available - and returning the connection to the pool occurs when you close or dispose the web response. In your case, you're not closing or disposing the response, so it's not being returned to the pool. There's a maximum number of connections to any particular host, which is configurable but usually shouldn't be changed. The default is two connections - which is why you're seeing two working responses and then a timeout.

I believe there's a finalizer *somewhere* which will release the connection when it notices the relevant object is eligible for garbage collection, but that's non-deterministic.

Basically: always close a web response, ideal using a `using` statement.

```
while (true)
{
    WebRequest http = WebRequest.Create("http://www.sina.com.cn");
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.LastModified);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate so much for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

You should call `response.Close()` when you have finishied working with respose or use `using(HttpWebResponse response ...` to close it automatically

Comment: I appreciate so much for your answer!